# MySQL GROUP BY overlapping time range

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I've got a MySql table like this:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|date       |time_from   |time_until |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|2017-09-01 |08:00:00    |12:00:00   |
|2017-09-01 |16:00:00    |18:00:00   |
|2017-09-02 |09:00:00    |11:00:00   |
|2017-09-08 |09:30:00    |13:00:00   |
|2017-09-15 |09:00:00    |11:00:00   |
|2017-09-22 |08:45:00    |11:15:00   |
|2017-09-22 |16:15:00    |19:30:00   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to group these data by overlapping time range for each weekday. Each group should show min and max time of der overlapping time range. so the result I need should look like:

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
|weekday    |time_from   |time_until |dates                            |
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
|thurday    |09:30:00    |11:00:00   |2017-09-01, 2017-09-08, 2017-... 
|thurday    |16:15:00    |18:00:00   |2017-09-01, 2017-09-22           |
|friday     |09:30:00    |13:00:00   |2017-09-22                       |
+-----------+------------+-----------+---------------------------------+
```

thanks for every advice! :-)

Comment: how is your approach so far?

Comment: Are these actual datetime types, or just strings?

Comment: these are date and time columns.

My approach so far is something like this: (but it seems to be wrong)
SELECT
 *
FROM
 (
  SELECT
   *,
   WEEKDAY( table.date )
   MAX( table.time_from )  AS max_time_from,
   MIN( table.time_until ) AS min_time_until
  FROM
   table
  GROUP BY
   table.date
 ) as tmp
GROUP BY
 tmp.weekday

Comment: Could you please fix or explain your sample result? Sep/22 is a friday, why is it listed in the 2nd row. You should also define what you mean by "overlapping time range", so not everyone has to think about it for 10 minutes (especially if (potentially) incorrect sample results are the only explanation). It seems to be the minimum timespan that every range that overlaps on a weekday has in common? What happens if you add a range on a thursday from 10:30 to 12? It makes thursday result from 10:30 to 11? And if you add a range from 8 to 20? Does it give empty ranges for thurday?

Comment: To get the "dates" field You might want to GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ' ') as dates to get it. I have a bit more problem to manage the overlaps.

Comment: the first table contains vacant time slots. I want to know if there is a vacant time slot for every weekday in my asked date range (e.g. september).
so the result shows that there is a vacant slot on thursday between 9:30 and 11:00 for all days.

Comment: That would be a good addition to your question. I still don't really see your result though: Are the dates in your first list the vacant times/opening hours or the appointments? I still don't understand the results, but I guess I wait until you fixed or explained the dates before I try to understand it (e.g.: none of your days in the first list is a thursday, but in your result you have thursdays and fridays; and Sep/22 is listed for both thursday and friday, and saturday Sep/02 is not listed at all)